# UIViewController presented modally show up shifted to the top

Tags: ios

I'm presenting a UIViewController with presentModalViewController:animated.

```
    CMImportViewControlleriPhone *import = [[CMImportViewControlleriPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"Import-iPhone" bundle:nil];
    [import setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [import setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:import animated:YES];
    [import release];
```

However the top bar is not visible, and it is seems shifter to the top (there is an empty space on the bottom).

This is viewDidLoad in which I set the Close button on the navigationItem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(closeButtonPushed:)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];
}
```

thanks

Comment: Is this an iPad or an iPhone app?

Comment: u have uinavigation controller

Comment: @Prince No, I don't have a UINavigationController, should I create one and show it modally instead ?

Comment: i think there is no need for navigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a navigation bar and then present modalView

```
CMImportViewControlleriPhone *obj = [[CMImportViewControlleriPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"Import-iPhone" bundle:nil];
[obj setDelegate:self];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[obj release];
[navigationController release];
```

hope this helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with iPhone remove

```
[import setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
```

Comment: I've removed it, but it is the same

Answer (score 0):

When you add a UIBarButtonItem, the NavigationController is nil, and navigationBar is nil also. So it doesn't work with navigationItem.

```
closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(closeButtonPushed:)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:closeButton];
```

You should add a NavigationController for the import object, and present it.

```
CMImportViewControlleriPhone *import = [[CMImportViewControlleriPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"Import-iPhone" bundle:nil];
[import setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[import setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:import];
[self presentModalViewController:import animated:YES];
[import release];
[nc release];
```